# How do I pass an enum to a method in a subclass (from a ViewController)?

Tags: objective-c

My SomeClass.h

```
typedef enum thing {stuff, foo, bar, etc} thing;

@interface SomeClass : UIView {
    NSNumber *aNumber;
    thing aThing;
}
```

My SomethingViewController.m

```
-(void)doSomething:(NSNumber *)n
         withThing:(id)t
{
    SomeClass *class = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithFrame:aRect];
    [class setAThing:(thing)t];
    [class setANumber:n];
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[self doSomething:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] withThing:foo];
```

This seems to work fine, aside from a warning about the withThing: making a pointer from an integer without a cast.

I guess my question is: Am I doing this right? Is there a another way that will not give me this warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is another way. In an enum, all of your "things" are associated with a integer. So if you change the `id` in your method to `thing`or `int` it should work without a warning. This is the way I do it all the time. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the enumeration's name instead of id in your withThing: argument. Then you can remove the cast from t.

Also, I recommend using capitalized names for enumerations.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that part of both yours and Sandro's answers had part of the answer. I should clarify that the enum is not in the SomethingViewController.h but in another class. using the enumeration name would not compile. The SomethingViewController.h said it expected a ")" after "thing". Anyway, changing to int and removing the cast did the trick. Is there no way to give both answers credit?

Comment: If that is the case, then you can create another class called Globals, and store your enumeration there. Then, import that class anywhere you need to call or access your enumeration. (Also, if you like more than one answer, up-voting is perfectly okay.)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote, but I will come back here and upvote you the minute I am able. Thanks again.